# Table the 8 first derivatives of Sin[x]

Tags: list-manipulation

I would get the 8 first derivatives of Sin[x] by using `Table` and `TableForm`. I put

```
Table[D[Sin[x,x],{8}]
```

but it returns

```
{-Sin[x],-Sin[x].....}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `Table[D[Sin[x], {x, i}], {i, 8}]`

Comment: As it is right now the question is trivial. But it could be interesting to consider more complicated function instead of  `Sin[x]` and see what are different strategies to calculate n-th derivative. Unfortunately I can't post comparison code as answer since the question is on hold already. Voted to re-open.

Comment: @BlacKow This question concerns a misunderstanding of `Table[]`. If you want to answer a question about calculation of n-th derivatives I suggest you start your own question and make a Q&A.

Comment: `Rest@NestList[ D[#, x] &, Sin[x], 8]`

Comment: @george2079 That was my point exactly. This method seems to be way faster than `Table`.

Answer (score 1):

You have errors all across your code.

Here is the working one:

```
Table[D[Sin[x], {x, n}], {n, 1, 8}]
(* {Cos[x], -Sin[x], -Cos[x], Sin[x], Cos[x], -Sin[x], -Cos[x], 
 Sin[x]} *)
```

Comment: Or somewhat more concisely using Map: `D[Sin[x], {x, #}] & /@ Range[8]`