# Finding the first five derivatives of (1 + x)^a at x = 0

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I would like to get The first five derivatives of `(1 + x)^a` for `x = 0` using `Table`.

I can do it for `x`, but I do not know how to do it for `x = 0`.

Comment: If you managed for any `x`, you can add `/.x->0` at the end of your code.

Comment: `Table[D[(1 + x)^a, {x, i}], {i, 1, 5}] /. x -> 0`

Comment: This should be an application of induction (without Mathematica ;-) ) and one would come up with `Product[a - i, {i, 0, n-1}]` for the n. derivative

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table the 8 first derivatives of Sin\[x\]](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130102/table-the-8-first-derivatives-of-sinx)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `Replace` you can define the derivatives using `Function`.

```
Table[
  Function[
    x,
    D[(1 + x)^a, {x, n}]
    ][x], 

  {n, 1, 5}
  ] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]